# Apache-Beam ImportError: No module named _pytest.config

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've created a Dataflow template to run with cron triggers and just after creation it runs successfully.

Here's [the code](https://github.com/WillianFuks/example_dataproc_twitter/blob/make_recommendations/dataflow/build_datastore_template.py) I'm using to create the template.

But after a while (normally in the next day) it starts to throw the following exception:

```
(4ba8b349f8644419): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 706, in run
    self._load_main_session(self.local_staging_directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 446, in _load_main_session
    pickler.load_session(session_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 247, in load_session
    return dill.load_session(file_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 363, in load_session
    module = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1090, in load_global
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/dill.py", line 423, in find_class
    return StockUnpickler.find_class(self, module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1124, in find_class
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named _pytest.config
```

[image]

And then if I re-make the template and try to run our jobs again it works, until next day when the same error message returns.

I've been trying to understand what's wrong but I couldn't so far. I thought on some sort of file having some time to live affecting the template or maybe my `config` import caused some conflict but this option doesn't quite explain why the job runs successfully at first.

If you need any more information please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Do you use custom `setup.py` file? 2. Why do you use PyTest module in the pipeline? If you do not use it in the pipeline, then replace global `import pytest` with local (in-function) imports when needed.

Comment: Hi Marcin, thanks for the comment. Here are the answers: 1. No, I did consider trying with setup.py but havent tried it so far. 2. I don't! Nowhere in the code do I use pytest...I have no idea why this exception is throwing with pytest. What we did observe though is that if we let it be run triggered by our crons then its working...we didn't have any more of this error since we turned our crons on...that means that what happened here remains a mystery for us and just happened when we manually ran the code and just the next day, the few first runs was just ok.